# echo [uint32]::maxvalue says 'uint32::maxvalue' instead of 4294967295

Tags: powershell

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> echo [uint32]::maxvalue
[uint32]::maxvalue
```

and

```
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> $mv = [uint32]::maxvalue
[DBG]: PS C:\Windows\system32>>> echo $mv
4294967295
```

I am sure powershell has some perfectly good reason for doing this   :-). Is there someway i can tell it not to do it. I am actually passing and int to a function and sometimes I want to pass maxvalue

I know I can do

```
$mv = [uint32]::maxvalue
MyFunc $mv
```

I am wondering if there is something like

```
MyFunc ([uint32]::maxvalue)
MyFunc `[uint32::maxvalue`
```

etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why is that the `echo` command is interpreting the argument as a `string` and not an arbitrary value.  Hence in the first example it's printing out the argument literally vs. interpreting it as a value.  In the second case though it's being interpreted as an expression and being assigned to a value.

You can reproduce this behavior by creating a function yourself that echos the output to the console.

```
function example { 
  param ([string]$arg)
  Write-Output $arg
}

example [uint]
> [uint]
example 42
> 42
```

You can also force the `echo` function to interpret it as a value by using `()`s to specify it's an expression

```
echo [uint32]::maxvalue
> [uint32]::maxvalue
echo ([uint32]::maxvalue)
> 4294967295
```

Comment: actually it was my own function. And I didnt specify a type - I guess it defaulted to string

Answer (score 3):

PowerShell uses two modes when it interperts a command, Argument mode and Expression mode (see the about_Parsing topic).

The following is parsed in Expression mode, that's why you get the value back.

```
$mv = [uint32]::maxvalue
echo $mv
```

In Argument mode everything is treated as a string unless it starts with one of the following characters:
$,@,',",(

```
echo [uint32]::maxvalue
```

The argument (-InputObject) is parsed as a string and echoed back literally. To evaluate it you need to force it to be recognised as an expression, enclosing it in parens do the job:

```
echo ([uint32]::maxvalue)
4294967295
```